# SNMPSharpnet SET negative value

Tags: c#, snmp

I am working on a program to automatically detect when certain settings get changed and send an SNMP set request to update that value.

I am utilizing SNMPSharpnet within C# and have located the correct OIB's to adjust, When I request the information I get the following responses

```
"(1.3.6.1.4.1.1963.20.10.10.10.1.14.0) (Integer32): 1094713344"
"(1.3.6.1.4.1.1963.20.10.10.10.1.16.0) (Integer32): -1025507328"
```

These numbers are not what are in the settings menu, the correct values are -112 and 12 respectively.

I send 12 to 1.3.6.1.4.1.1963.20.10.10.10.1.16.0 and it updates correctly to 12 in the settings.

However, When I send -1025507328 to 1.3.6.1.4.1.1963.20.10.10.10.1.16.0 it shows 144 within the settings.

I've noticed anytime I try to send a negative number it reverts to a positive number. I've verified it's wanting an *integer*, I've tried sending -0x70 and -112 and it still shows up as 144.

ADDITIONAL INFO
When I send the values I have the device resend to verify it received what I sent. When I get the replies back I get

```
sysDescr(1.3.6.1.4.1.1963.20.10.10.10.1.14.0) (Integer32): 1095761920
sysDescr(1.3.6.1.4.1.1963.20.10.10.10.1.16.0) (Integer32): -1025376256
Agent response 1.3.6.1.4.1.1963.20.10.10.10.1.14.0: 12
Agent response 1.3.6.1.4.1.1963.20.10.10.10.1.16.0: -112
```

I refresh the site to verify settings and 14.0 = 12 and 16.0 = +144

Comment: It's more likely to be caused by the SNMP agent, so involve its vendor in your troubleshooting.